# How to check if a field is blank or not?

Tags: php, html, redirect

So I have this code in PHP, and it's not working for some reason that I don't know:

```
if(!empty($ccle))
{
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}

else
{
    header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}
```

What I want is: if the "ccle" field is empty, then go to google.com
Or if the "ccle" field is not empty (Where ever was the value) then go to yahoo.com

How to make it do that?

Comment: How are you getting the ``$ccle`` variable? Is it from the URL? If so, you should change it to $_GET['ccle']

Comment: You also want your script to `die()` right after that `if` block in order to prevent potential redirection problems.

Comment: removed the 'arrays' tag, since there aren't any arrays anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to switch them...

```
if(!empty($ccle))
{
    // Go to Yahoo if $ccle is NOT empty
    header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}
else
{
    // Else, go to Google
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
```

Just to elaborate. What your `if` statement is saying is...

```
if($ccle IS NOT empty)
```

The exclamation in PHP is the logical **not** operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to redirect to Google when it's empty and Yahoo when it's not. You would then change:

```php
if(!empty($ccle))
```

To:

```php
if(empty($ccle))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(empty($ccle)) {
    header('Location: http://google.com/');
} else {
    header('Location: http://yahoo.com/');
}
```

This should perform as you described. The only difference is I've removed the exclamation. Your original code said if ccle is ndt empty, go to google. This says if it is empty go to google.

You have to make sure this is called before anything else is output to the browser. If it's still not working post any errors or what the output actually is.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are spot on

i'd just like to add the the `!` part of `!empty` signifies "NOT", so what you've been typing in is essentially "if the field is NOT empty, then go to google" instead of "if the field is empty, then go to google"

also, how are you getting the variable? if you have a form similar to this:

```
<input name="ccl" type="text" id="ccl" />
```

and something similar to this for grabbing the form contents and putting it into a variable,

```
<?php
//making sure the forms button is pressed
if(isset($_POST["button"])){
//grabbing input and putting into a variable 
$ccl = ($_POST["ccl"]);
}
?>
```

then the other answers provided should work